# n <version> command does not activate specified version

Tags: node.js, n

Currently I have two versions of node installed on a Jenkins server.

```
$ n list
node/10.9.0
node/12.14.1
```

I'm trying to switch to version 10.9.0 for a specific build which requires it.

I've tried first by using `n <version>` but the latest 12.14.1 still shows as active:

```
$ n 10.9.0
installed : v10.9.0 to /opt/jenkins/n/bin/node
   active : v12.14.1 at /bin/node
```

I've also tried `n use <version>` which just follows up with a prompt.

```
$ n use 10.9.0
>
```

I've read various articles on this but could not get any commands to effectively switch versions.

i.e. https://blog.logrocket.com/switching-between-node-versions-during-development/

Below is the n exectuable.

```
which n
/opt/jenkins/n/bin/n
```

Versions appear to get installed under the below directory:

```
/opt/jenkins/n/n/versions/node/
10.9.0  
12.14.1
```

Below are the contents of `/opt/jenkins/n/bin/`

```
chrome-debug -> ../lib/node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-core/scripts/manual-chrome-launcher.js
lighthouse -> ../lib/node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-cli/index.js
n
ng
node
nodejs
npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
n-uninstall
n-update
```

How can I switch node versions with n?  Is there anything in the above that is missing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: check path, seems added too many path variable

Comment: This is current path:

echo $PATH
/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/jenkins/n/bin:/opt/jenkins/.local/bin:/opt/jenkins/bin

I see /opt/jenkins/n/bin which is where all the node executables are.  Is something missing from the path maybe or do you mean the contents of the folder are too much?

Comment: i think, there are another instance of node js in folder
`/opt/jenkins/bin`

Comment: clean /opt/jenkins/ folder and install again

Comment: Question: are node and nodejs the same thing?  I have all of the n files under `/opt/jenkins/n/bin`.   Only one nodejs is there.  Interestingly the path shows `/opt/jenkins/bin` which doesn't exist

Comment: if u install using brew, apt-get, they call it node js

Comment: ok, I suspect there is some issue in the overall setup.  Thanks for the help, will post back once I've made some progress.

Comment: `/bin/node` points to `/opt/jenkins/n/bin/nodejs` so after running `n <version>` this updates `/opt/jenkins/n/bin/node` only.  It needs to be copied to nodejs `cp /opt/jenkins/n/bin/node /opt/jenkins/n/bin/nodejs` and after that the correct node version is used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After running `which node` the path shows `/bin/node`.

`/bin/node` is a symlink to `/opt/jenkins/n/bin/nodejs`.

```
$ ll /bin/node
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jan 28 08:26 /bin/node -> /opt/jenkins/n/bin/nodejs
```

When installing, with `n <version>` it updates `/opt/jenkins/n/bin/node` only.

```
$ n 10.9.0
   installed : v10.9.0 to /opt/jenkins/n/bin/node
      active : v12.14.1 at /bin/node
```

Once this is done, node needs to be copied to nodejs.

```
$ cp /opt/jenkins/n/bin/node /opt/jenkins/n/bin/nodejs
$ node -v
v10.9.0
```

Answer (score 32):

If you use `brew` and see something like this:

```
$ n                                                                                                                                          
     copying : node/16.19.1
   installed : v16.19.1 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v19.7.0 at /opt/homebrew/bin/node
```

Just run `brew unlink node` to let `n` manage node versions again.

Answer (score 5):

You have copies of node installed to multiple locations, but only one of the locations is managed by `n` (which is set using `N_PREFIX`). Your `PATH` includes the copy installed by `n` later, so is not run when you just type `node`.

See also `n doctor` which looks for a few configuration issues including this one.

One possible solution is to have the location you want to use earlier in your path, another is to delete the node copy you don't want. However, you can run the `n` managed copy of node directly too which might be a good match for a CI  type situation and not require any configuration changes.

`n run` (or `n use`) run the version of node you specify as a one-off command. e.g.

```
$ n run 10.9.0 --version
v10.9.0
$ n run 10.9.0  -e 'console.log("hello")'
hello
$ n run 10.9.0  my-script.js
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to get it working by copying the n updated `/opt/jenkins/n/bin/node` to `/opt/jenkins/n/bin/nodejs` which the `bin/node` symlink was pointing to.  I tried `n use` in my initial post, as well as `n run` but I don't think I appended `--version` at the end which may be why I was left with a prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the best option, but I manually did an `export PATH=` with whatever was the output of `echo $PATH` minus the substring `/Users/achraf/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin:` (that was at the very beginning) and now my active version is not shadowed anymore.

Comment: nvm is another node manager and works by modifying the path. You could disable or uninstall it if you are using n.

Comment: Kudos @shadowspawn! Just tried `nvm deactivate` and it printed: `/Users/achraf/.nvm/*/bin removed from ${PATH}` 